# SELECT values to create a unique row with optional foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016-express

I have several tables in a SQL Server database, two of them (`Table1` and `Table2`) I would like to select a specific subset from, to fill in a third table (`Table3`).

In `Table1` there are 25 columns, from which I am only interested in three, let's call them `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`. All three are not unique in this table, but I would like to extract the unique pairs, as follows:

- `Col1` + `Col2` = Unique Key for `Table3`.
- `Col3` + `Col2` = *Optional*, foreign key into `Table2`.

To extract the unique keys for `Table3` from `Table1` the following SQL works fine:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

However this is missing `Col3`. The first problem is that `Col3` can't simply be added as part of the `GROUP BY` as there can be different values for it, which causes duplicate combinations of `Col1` + `Col2` to be returned.

This is where `Table2` comes into play; `Col3` + `Col2` form a unique key into `Table2`, but not every combination is present (which is helpful), as a `JOIN` can be used to filter away the invalid combinations:

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3 
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON b.Col3 = a.Col3 AND b.Col2 = a.Col2
GROUP BY a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3
```

Now my final problem, unfortunately there are some (very few) combinations that do result in duplicate `Col1` + `Col2` keys for `Table3`.

If we assume it is okay to lose some `Col3` values, how can I write a `SELECT` to extract the three columns, ensuring that the combination `Col1` + `Col2` is unique? And if possible keeping a `Col3` value that provides a valid key combination in `Table2`.

I've messed about with adding `TOP 1` but I've failed in getting anything to work to my liking...

*EDIT*: Example data as requested.

```
Table1
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|  100 |   00 |  010 |
|  100 |   10 |  020 |
|  200 |   00 |  030 |
|  300 |   00 |  040 |
|  300 |   00 |  040 |
|  400 |   10 |  050 |
|  400 |   10 |  060 |
|  400 |   10 |  070 |

Table2
| Colx | Col2 | Col3 |
|  car |   00 |  010 |
|  cat |   10 |  030 |
|  dog |   00 |  040 |
|  bee |   10 |  040 |
|  eye |   10 |  060 |
|  bit |   10 |  070 |

Table3
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|  100 |   00 |  010 |
|  100 |   10 |  020 |
|  200 |   00 |  030 |
|  300 |   00 |  040 |
|  400 |   00 |  060 |
```

The third table shows the result I am looking for - the table only contains unique combinations of `Col1` + `Col2` and also contains a `Col3` values, preferably one that provides a value combination with `Col2` in the second table (ie. the last entry, 400, 00, 060).

I hope this provides a little more clarity.

Comment: If you don't actually care about `Col3`, why don't you remove it from the `GROUP BY` and use an aggregate function in your `SELECT`, for example `MAX(Col3)`?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way?

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, Max(a.Col3)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON b.Col3 = a.Col3 AND b.Col2 = a.Col2
GROUP BY a.Col1, a.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

"The first problem is that Col3 can't simply be added as part of the GROUP BY as there can be different values for it, which causes duplicate combinations of Col1 + Col2 to be returned."

You can put the queries for different values into a select union subquery as a derived table, and group by on the derived table.